Audio distortion in 24.04
I have install Ubuntu 24.04 in my Lenovo Ideapad Slim 3, i have audio issue, when I play audio, there's a crackling sound and sometimes it is low volume. I have no issue in bluetooth speakers or headphones, just my internal speaker
I have updated 24.10, and the issue is there again, can you guys help me fix this
I tried this and nothing happened https://www.reddit.com/r/linux_gaming/comments/1d1ef61/pipewire_audio_distortion_and_crackling_fix/
cheesecake@cheesecake:~$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], device 0: HDA Analog (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], device 3: HDMI1 (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], device 4: HDMI2 (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], device 5: HDMI3 (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], device 31: HDA Analog Deep Buffer (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

cheesecake@cheesecake:~$ pactl info
Server String: /run/user/1000/pulse/native
Library Protocol Version: 35
Server Protocol Version: 35
Is Local: yes
Client Index: 116
Tile Size: 65472
User Name: cheesecake
Host Name: cheesecake
Server Name: PulseAudio (on PipeWire 1.2.4)
Server Version: 15.0.0
Default Sample Specification: float32le 2ch 48000Hz
Default Channel Map: front-left,front-right
Default Sink: alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3-platform-skl_hda_dsp_generic.HiFi__Speaker__sink
Default Source: alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1f.3-platform-skl_hda_dsp_generic.HiFi__Mic1__source
Cookie: 6d01:5170

cheesecake@cheesecake:~$ uname -r
6.11.0-8-generic

S   ID  QUANT   RATE    WAIT    BUSY   W/Q   B/Q  ERR FORMAT           NAME     
S   30      0      0    ---     ---   ---   ---     0                  Dummy-Dri
S   31      0      0    ---     ---   ---   ---     0                  Freewheel
S   48      0      0    ---     ---   ---   ---     0                  Midi-Brid
S   54      0      0    ---     ---   ---   ---     0                  bluez_mid
S   57      0      0    ---     ---   ---   ---     0                  alsa_outp
S   58      0      0    ---     ---   ---   ---     0                  alsa_outp
S   59      0      0    ---     ---   ---   ---     0                  alsa_outp
R   60   2048  48000  73.2us  18.4us  0.00  0.00    0    S32LE 2 48000 alsa_outp
R   93   2048  48000  24.8us  34.0us  0.00  0.00    0    F32LE 2 48000  + Brave
S   61      0      0    ---     ---   ---   ---     0                  alsa_inpu
S   62      0      0    ---     ---   ---   ---     0                  alsa_inpu
S   80      0      0    ---     ---   ---   ---     0                  v4l2_inpu

# System Details Report
---

## Report details
- **Date generated:**                              2024-10-18 19:06:51

## Hardware Information:
- **Hardware Model:**                              Lenovo IdeaPad 3 14ITL6
- **Memory:**                                      16.0 GiB
- **Processor:**                                   11th Gen Intel® Core™ i7-1165G7 × 8
- **Graphics:**                                    Intel® Xe Graphics (TGL GT2)
- **Disk Capacity:**                               (null)

## Software Information:
- **Firmware Version:**                            GGCN60WW
- **OS Name:**                                     Ubuntu 24.10
- **OS Build:**                                    (null)
- **OS Type:**                                     64-bit
- **GNOME Version:**                               47
- **Windowing System:**                            Wayland
- **Kernel Version:**                              Linux 6.11.0-8-generic

